# How to cycle through siblings using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I have the folowing code:

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="selected">A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
</div>
<button id="next">next!</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
});
```

What i want is loop through the divs in the container. I can do this to cycle:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    if ($(".selected").next().length == 0) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected").siblings(":nth-child(1)").addClass("selected");
    }
    else {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

But i think there is a simpler way. How can i make it simpler ? (I don't mind if you don't use the `next()` function).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S28uC/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I 'd prefer `siblings.first()` instead of `siblings(":nth-child(1)")`, but in essence you won't be able to wrap around without using some variant of `next().length`.

**Update:** If I were writing this from scratch, this is how I 'd do it:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    var $selected = $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    var divs = $selected.parent().children();
    divs.eq((divs.index($selected) + 1) % divs.length).addClass("selected");
});
```

This approach is motivated by two factors:

1. When you want to cycle over a collection indefinitely, modulo comes to mind
2. Getting rid of the `if` makes for smarter-looking code

When setting the value of `divs` I preferred `$selected.parent().children()` over the equivalent `$selected.siblings().add($selected)` as a matter of taste -- there are practically endless possibilities.

Comment: OMG How could I forget about modulo?! That little operator never ceases to amaze me. +1 for such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is this :

```
$("#container").find("div:eq(0)").addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

```
...
var selected = $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
if (jQuery(selected).next().addClass("selected").length == 0
   {jQuery(selected).siblings().first().addClass("selected");};
...
```

In old good AI manner you try to do the deed (addClass), if it worked (length <> 0) nothing more to do, otherwise you try again on the first of the siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var  cont   = $('.container'),
     i      = 0;
$("#next").on('click', function() {
    cont.children().removeClass('selected');
    i += 1;
    if ( i === document.querySelectorAll('.container div').length ) { i = 0; }
    cont.children().eq(i).addClass('selected');
});
```

```js
var cont = $('.container'),
 i      = 0;
    
$("#next").on('click', function() {
    cont.children().removeClass('selected');
    
    // increase index for each click
    i += 1;
    // reset i if it reached to last index
    //(hack to force next to go back to first element when we are at the end)
    if ( i === document.querySelectorAll('.container div').length ) {
      i = 0;
    }
  
    cont.children().eq(i).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="selected">A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
</div>

<button id="next">next!</button>
```

simply you will increase `i` for each click and when it reach the end (`div`s length ) it will be reset.