# How to add if statements to loop the images around?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code makes the 'li' move like I want to but when I get to the last 'li' and click next it keeps moving and the 'li' moves out of the users view. I want to know how to loop it so the first 'li' shows up again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#right').click(function() {
            $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
                right: '+=292px'
                }, 500);
        });
        $('#left').click(function() {
            $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
                right: '-=292px'
                }, 500);
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/7/) to see an example

Comment: you will need to check the index of the currently active one and see how many on left or right, though here you are manually calculating the px. Checkout the similar answer from previous SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672261/cycle-active-class-with-carousel It looks more generic solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inner = $('.carousel-inner'),
        slides = inner.find('li'),
        width = slides.eq(0).outerWidth(true),
        max = (width * slides.length) - width;

    $('#right, #left').on('click', function () {
        var currRight = parseInt(inner.css('right'), 10), move;
        if (this.id === 'right') {
            move = currRight === max ? 0 : currRight+width;
        } else {
            move = currRight === 0 ? max : currRight-width;
        }
        inner.animate({ right: move }, 500);
    });
});
```

The top four lines cache elements and set up a few basic variables such as the max `right` value that can used and the `width` of the slides.

I've then combined the `click` events to avoid repetition. The first line of the click event defines `currRight` as `$('.carousel-inner')`'s current CSS `right` value as well as `move` which is used later on.

`if (this.id === 'right'){ /* #right */ }else{ /* #left */ }` checks whether the `id` of the clicked element is `right` or `left`. The code inside the if statement just checks to see whether the slider is at zero (the beginning) or max (the end) and then sets the `move` variable to the correct value.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/10/

**Update**: To make the slides move on a timer add this after the click event is attached:

```
function setTimer(){
    clearTimeout(window.slideTimer);
    window.slideTimer = setTimeout(function(){ $('#right').trigger('click'); }, 5000);
};

setTimer();
```

Then add `setTimer();` right after `inner.animate({ right: move }, 500);` and everything will work as expected.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/14/

Comment: I like that the code is shorter too. I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7F534/) but the code is longer and messier right?

Comment: One problem though. Script does not work in Google Chrome and IE. Why could it be??

Comment: @andresr - I've just tested it in Google Chrome and it's working fine for me. Could you check the fiddle in both those browsers? If it works in them but not on your site then it might be another script on your page interfering with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `totalItems` variable which will represent the total number of items in the carousel, and a `currentItem` variable which will represent the number of the current item being displayed (i.e. a number from 1 to totalItems). Then, simply check if it's the last item, and if it is, move the position back to the first one. Check out the [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4kzj/1/), where it works in both directions. Here's example JavaScript, with everything written out for clarity.

```
var totalItems = $('.carousel-inner li').length;
var currentItem = 1;

$('#right').click(function () {
    if (currentItem === totalItems) {
        // We've reached the end -- go to the beginning again
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '-=' + 292 * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
        }, 500);
        currentItem = 1;
    } else {
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '+=292px'
        }, 500);
        currentItem += 1;
    }
});
$('#left').click(function () {
    if (currentItem === 1) {
        // We're at the beginning -- loop back to the end
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '+=' + 292 * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
        }, 500);
        currentItem = totalItems;
    } else {
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '-=292px'
        }, 500);
        currentItem -= 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I set the timer so it can move on its own. I have the setTimeout but it only moves the first 2 "li".

Comment: I'd use `setInterval` for that so it will repeat.

Comment: Yeah I got it thanks. Reading into .hover() clearInterval and onMouseout setInterval. Trying to learn as much as I can thanks to you guys here in stackoverflow for making it easier for me lol.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFxcq/8/) for a working approach. For the right click.

Basically, each time you click "Right", you'll test to compare the distance traveled by the items and compare that to the maximum distance allowed based on the total number of items.

```
var slideWidth = 292;    
$('#right').click(function() {
    if(parseInt($('.carousel-inner li').css('right')) == slideWidth*($('.carousel-inner li').length-1)) {
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '0px'
    , 500);
    }
    else {
        $('.carousel-inner li').animate({
            right: '+=' + slideWidth + 'px'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct.  If you read my answer, I updated for 'Right' only.  It would e simple for the OP to make changes 'Left'.  The key is that he has a working sample of 'right' with which to work.